# X axis labels cut off in Jupyter with R

Tags: r, plot, jupyter

I'm having the same problem as the person from [How can I make my vertical labels fit within my plotting window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128526/how-can-i-make-my-vertical-labels-fit-within-my-plotting-window) but in Jupyter. When I make a barplot in R within Jupyter any long vertical x-axis labels get cut off. For example

```
animals = c("dog","cat","squirrel","dog","fox","dog","llama","cat","tyrannosaurus rex")
sorted <- sort(table(animals), decreasing=T)
barplot(sorted, las = 2)
```

Using the solution to the linked question

```
animals = c("dog","cat","squirrel","dog","fox","dog","llama","cat","tyrannosaurus rex")
sorted <- sort(table(animals), decreasing=T)
par(mar = c(15,4,4,2) + 0.1) 
barplot(sorted, las = 2)
```

works in the R gui for mac but not in Jupyter.

I've also tried playing with repr and its options, for example

```
library(repr)
options(repr.plot.width=4, repr.plot.height=4)
```

But while that can shrink and stretch the plot, the bottom still gets cut-off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of searching, still not able to get it right. I was able to get it to work with ggplot instead

```
library(ggplot2)
animals = c("dog","cat","squirrel","dog","fox","dog","llama","cat","tyrannosaurus rex")
bars<- ggplot()+
    aes(x=animals)+
    geom_bar(stat="count")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
print(bars)
```